# Creating an object from a text file with multiple objects

Tags: java, file, object, text, arraylist

I need to read information about cars from a txt file and then saves it to an `ArrayList`. The first line in the file tells you how many cars are within the file.

The txt file looks like this:

```
3
2011
Toyota 
Corolla
2009
Honda
Civic 
2012
Honda
Accord
```

and so on..

I know how to create an object from a users input, but I am trying to edit it so reads it from a file.

Comment: Please include the code you currently have along with what exactly is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually I would suggest using a `FileReader`, but you said that you are refactoring code which reads this information from the user. I guess, you are reading the input with a `Scanner`, so the easiest way to change this is by replacing

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

with this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("someFile.txt"));
```

You can then use the `Scanner` like that:

```
String fileName = "cars.txt";
List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("someFile.txt"))){
    int count = sc.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int year = sc.nextInt();
        String brand = sc.next();
        String type = sc.next();
        cars.add(new Car(year, brand, type));
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("error reading cars from file "+fileName);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Also use `sc.hasNext()` and `sc.hasNextInt()` before you read from the `Scanner`, since your code might otherwise throw exceptions if the file doesn't have valid content..

You can see the `Car` class in another (distinct) answer I posted

Comment: I already did that part, I know how to read the text file. The issue that I am having is that I want to save each part of the car; year, name, model. Then I need to use those saved variables and make a object with them.

Comment: I added the part where you use the `Scanner` for reading values

Comment: Ok so I tried the code and it worked if I set the count my self, instead of reading it from the file.

Comment: So basically if i put count = 3; it works fine but if I make it read the first number from the file (the 3) it skips a line so my output is {( ,2011, toyota)(corolla, 2009, honda), etc)

Comment: i tried this code with the file you posted above and it worked fine.. did you really use exactly this code and you have the same text in the file?

Comment: Yeah I did the exact same code but I added: string extraline = reader.readLine() after the counter and it seems to work fine now so thanks! I guess it may have been skipping a line or something. Thanks for you help I'll mark your answer correct.

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't just want to refactor code which used a `Scanner`, you can do it with a `FileReader`:

```
String fileName = "cars.txt";
List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))){
    int count = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int year = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        String brand = reader.readLine();
        String type = reader.readLine();
        cars.add(new Car(year, brand, type));
    }
} catch (IOException | NumberFormatException e) {
    System.err.println("error reading cars from file "+fileName);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Please note that you might need to do proper error handling in the catch block. Also the reader might return `null` as he reaches the end of the file, just in case you want to validate the input coming from the file (which you always should)..

And here is your `Car` class:

```
public class Car {
    private final int year;
    private final String brand;
    private final String type;

    public Car(int year, String brand, String type) {
        this.year = year;
        this.brand = brand;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

Comment: since I had bad experiences in the past: please note that it is not only accepted, [but desired](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25210/316262) to answer twice if you have two distinct answers